# move to the end of the text in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to have textbox always focused. So I decided to add `LostFocus` handler

```
this.textBox1.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(delegate(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
                                                   {
                                                      this.textBox1.Focus();
                                                   });
```

But when I press buttons on the form and then begin to write into textbox again - it starts to  add symbols before current text in textbox. For the example if I've got text in textbox `abcd` and then press button on the form and start to write again `1234` I have in the textbox text `1234abcd`.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.textBox1.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(delegate(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
                                                   {
                                                      this.textBox1.Focus();
                                                       this.textBox1.AppendText("") ;
                                                   });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this.textBox1.Focus();
this.textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use select method like this:

```
    void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
```